# Run ant target with config property as parameter

Tags: ant

Is it possible to run custom ant task from command line with overridden configuration property?

Let's say that I want to override `force` property for `copy` task which is called within my custom task.
Is it possible to execute something like this from command line:

```
ant [myTask] -Dcopy.force=true
```

What's the name of this property if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `-D` option to populate any property.
`ant [target] -Dforce=true`